# On enter,jump to next EditText issue

Tags: java, android

I have 3 EditTexts in a row but on 3 different layouts. I set them up so when i click enter,it will jump to the next EditText from that row,on the next layout.The problem is that when i click enter from the first EditText on the row,it goes to the third.From the third it goes to the second and from the second to the first.It's like i press enter on the first EditText,it goes to the second and then to the third on the same enter.
How can i stop it from jumping for example from the first EditText to the second and then the third on the same press of the enter key?

Here's some of my code :

```
et.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v1, int keyCode, KeyEvent KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        l2.getChildAt(localizarer).requestFocus();
        return true;
    }
});

et2.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v2, int keyCode, KeyEvent KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        l3.getChildAt(localizarer).requestFocus();
        return true;
    }
});

et3.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v3, int keyCode, KeyEvent KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        l1.getChildAt(localizarer).requestFocus();
        return true;
    }
});
```

It's like i need some kind of `break` function,lol.
How can i fix this ?
Thanks and have a nice day/night !

Fixed by doing this :

```
et.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
        {
            // Perform action on key press
            l2.getChildAt(localizarer).requestFocus();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

But now an older issue is back,it jumps to my second row of edittexts instead of going to the first child in the layout it goes to the second..

Comment: Maybe you should supply your creation routines.

Comment: I have,here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171822/getchildat-getting-it-wrong . It started working when i placed onKeyListeners to all my et's but after i modified the onkeylisteners it started jumping  one row below again and not detecting the first child

Answer (score 0):

Are your edit texts defined in your xml do you have them in the corrent order there? 
if that doesn't work you can use

```
android:nextFocusDown
```

to set the order

Comment: No,they are not defined,they are created dynamically.The problem is not the focus order but the fact that it calls my OnKeyListener twice.So it goes to the second EditText but then calls the listener again and goes to the third EditText,all in one Enter key.I guess this is the issue but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried letting android decide instead of forcing the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
et1.requestFocus();
```

Instead of

```
l1.getChildAt(localizarer).requestFocus();
```

Comment: Because they are created dynamically :) There's no et1,i create an undefined number of et1's,et2's and et3's.I Fixed the issue,i'll edit and write the fix but now i stumbled upon an older issue of mine which i can't figure out..